# Best way to fit an equation for the given graph

Tags: numerical-methods

I have 450 pair $(x,y)$ of data. The plot is like this:

[image]

I need to fit an equation: $y=f(x)$ for the given data, and to find out values of $y$ when $x=500$.

Now, my question is:

> What kind of equation (e.g., linear, quadratic, cubic, exponential, ...) would fit the data most? And, after choosing the type, what would be best way to find the coefficients?

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, it is a series of dotted line segments. I have a look at the Step functions and Splines. But not sure how to proceed!

Comment: @Amzoti OK, thanks. But how can I get the estimated $y$ when $x =500$ here?

Comment: @Amzoti *"You just have a magnitude over a range that contains $x=500$"* - not actually. I just have the data: 450 pair ($x$ ranging from $1$ to $450$), and I need the best possible guess for $y$ when $x=500$. It's typically an extrapolation problem, but normal extrapolation will obviously give bad results!

Comment: Extrapolation is inherently risky, and in this case I think you could make quite different values at $x=500$ look reasonable. Some kind of understanding of intuition about the process could really help to come up with a functional form with some constant parameters to fit.